# How can I implement remote server which will run on separate process in android?

Tags: java, android, service

I need to create two different applications (two different processes) in Android. One will have activity and the other should just be service which would be started from the activity code.
I need it to be separate because in service I need to create one more instance of SDK that I am using in my activity.
I can't find any example how to implement and connect these two applications, does anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest not doing it at all.  Android is really not set up to be a server, with power limitations and the ability of the OS to kill background processes at any time it just isn't meant to be reliable-  which is exactly what a server needs.  I would suggest reposting with more details of what you need (because "need to create one more instance of SDK" doesn't make any sense-  SDKs don't have instances, and why would you not be able to do more than 1 instance in your Activity) and seeing if you can get alternative architetures.

Comment: I have chat app and I want to create a service that will send messages to that chat so I can simulate a conversation. If I want to do that, I need to create two users, one from main activity, other from service. I can't do that in one application, because the SDK doesn't allow me to register more than one user in one application, that's why I need service to be other application.

Comment: If you're communicating across a chat API, why not just have two instances of the same app on two devices each register a different user and talk to each other?  I'm going to assume this is for some type of test, as it doesn't really make sense to have that as part of the normal functionality of the app.